# How do I require a file from a parent folder in node JS

Tags: node.js, directory

I am trying to use a var from a file in a parent folder, and I am getting an error

Here is my the structure of my folders and files:

```
Folder1
    file1
    Folder2
        file2
```

Here is my code (I am trying to use a var from file 1 in file 2):

```
const fileOne = require('../folder1/file1');
```

I get this error: `Error: Cannot find module '../folder1/file1'`

Comment: should be an issue with case sensitivity. Your directory is named as `Folder1` (Pascal case) while you require `folder1` (lower case)

Answer (score 0):

**file1.js**

```
var name = 'foobar';
exports.name = name;
```

**file2.js**

```
const { name } = require('../file1');

console.log(name); // prints foobar
```

Then if you run

```
$ node file2.js
foobar
```

Basically,

```
../file1
```

Goes to the parent folder and looks for file1.js
Make sure you are exporing the variable from file1.js and importing it like the following:

```
const { someVariable} = require('../fileName')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try:

```
const fileOne = require('../folder1/file1.js'); //
```

and make sure you are exporting it correctly,

```
module.exports = whatever or { whatevers if there are more than 2} ;
```